# Как передать ArrayList<String> через intent? FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION

Tags: android, android-sdk, activity, android-intent

Добрый день.

Подскажите как передать ArrayList через intenten? 
Отправляю так:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        ArrayList<String> arrayList = dj.getArrayList();
        intent.putExtra("json", arrayList);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
```

И получаю так:

```
//Получаем json
    Intent intent = this.getIntent();
        if(intent !=null) {
            resultJson = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("json");
        }
```

Все время приложение падает и появляется ошибка:

```
E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!
```

Comment: Приведите полный стектрейс, пожалуйста.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja как такого стек трейса и нет. Все что я вижу это в Android Monitor:  E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Данная ошибка указывает видимо на то, что размер передаваемых данных велик для интента (более 1 Мб)

Comment: Как тогда передают данные в таком случае?

Comment: @АнатолийФерисов Через сам интент можно передать данные объемом не более 1 МБ

Comment: Ок, понял но как тогда передают данные в таком случае?

Comment: Разработчики рекомендуют не превышать порог 100кб, а ещё лучше 50кб, т.к 1 мб это общий буфер для всех IPC операций - http://blog.sqisland.com/2016/09/transactiontoolargeexception-crashes-nougat.html?showComment=1474217554727#c1100089308063228299

Comment: @АнатолийФерисов например писать в файл, а интентом передавать только путь до файла или использовать БД и передавать ID записи, возможно SharedPreferences, хотя они и не предназначены для такого использования и это будет костыль

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего вы неверно помещаете данные в интент.
Для этих целей есть другой метод:

```
intent.putStringArrayListExtra("json", arrayList);
```

Comment: я пробовал такой вариант он тоже не работает.

Comment: Если симметрично пишете и читаете правильными методами, и все равно не работает, значит превышен лимит, как пишут в другом ответе.

Answer (score -1):

1)Сеарилузйте класс

```
public class Data implements Serializable {
    ...
}
```

2)Кладите в `İntent` так

```
Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity1.this, RegisterActivity2.class);
intent.putExtra("nvp", nameValuePairs);
startActivity(intent);
```

3)берите так

```
ArrayList<NVP> nameValuePairs = (ArrayList<NVP>) intent.getSerializable("nvp");
```

Comment: Сериализовать нужно класс в котором передаю или получаю?

Comment: ArrayList уже имплементирует интерфейс Serializable

Comment: Отдаете * Это делается так.Создю класс держут там данные и тот класс сеаризуют и передают без сереализации ничего не получишь

Comment: @pavlofff давайте он попробуэт и это заработает )Я вас уверяю)

Comment: @elik не работает. Сериализовал класс в котором передаю. Поменял передачу на такую:`Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);                  
   ArrayList<String> arrayList = dj.getArrayList();
        intent.putExtra("json", arrayList);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish()`

Comment: Что вы предлагаете сериализовать в ArrayList, состоящий из String, если там уже все и без вас сериализовано?